# How to add additional fee to subtotal of checkout/cart using events and observers? magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, event-observer, addtocart, quote

Basically, I am trying to add additional fees to the subtotal of checkout/cart based on product_type. Here is what I tried but I am not able to get print_r($item->getBasePrice()); because I want to add addbaseprice of item with additional fee such as finalPrice = $item->getBasePrice() + 10; and do something like below for each item in the quote based on product type. It would be great if anyone can guide me through this as it would be really a great learning experience. I also looked up on the web but couldn't find anything relevant.

```
$quote->collectTotals();
$item
            //         ->setConvertedPrice($finalPrice)
            //         ->setCustomPrice($finalPrice)
            //         ->setOriginalCustomPrice($finalPrice);
            //     $item->calcRowTotal();
```

***\app\code\KGF\Checkout\etc\events.xml***

```
<event name="checkout_cart_save_before">
        <observer name="kgf_checkout_cart_save_before" instance="KGF\Checkout\Observer\CartSaveBefore" />
</event>
```

***\app\code\KGF\Checkout\Observer\CartSaveBefore.php***

```
<?php

namespace KGF\Checkout\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface;

class CartSaveBefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer){

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        /** @var \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession */
        $checkoutSession = $objectManager->create("Magento\Checkout\Model\Session");

        $quote = $checkoutSession->getQuote();
        //print_r($quote->debug());//Gives information about quote but no information about its items
        $quote->collectTotals();
        foreach ($quote->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {//DOES NOT EXECUTE
            print_r($item->getBasePrice());
        }

        $cart = $observer->getCart();
        $quote_cart = $cart->getQuote();
        //print_r($quote_cart->debug());//Gives information about quote but no information about its items
        foreach($quote_cart->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){//DOES EXECUTE BUT DOES NOT GIVE BASE PRICE
           print_r($item->getBasePrice());
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are many places where you need to add the custom fee to avoid any issues. I'll suggest you go through the following free extension : [link](https://github.com/sivajik34/Custom-Fee-Magento2)